# Set a reactive layout in Meteor with Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Is there a way to set a reactive layout in meteor with iron router?

For example:

```
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  layoutTemplate: Session.get('fullscreen') ? 'layoutFull' : 'layout'
});
```

Then a link in both layouts with:

```
<a href="" data-action="toggleFullscreen" class="b-button">Toggle Fullscreen</a>
```

And then in both layouts something like this:

```
  Template.layoutFull.events({
    'click [data-action=toggleFullscreen]': function() {
      Session.set('fullscreen', !Session.get('fullscreen'));
    }
  });

  Template.layout.events({
    'click [data-action=toggleFullscreen]': function() {
      Session.set('fullscreen', !Session.get('fullscreen'));
    }
  });
```

The issue I'm running into is `Router.configure` isn't setting `layoutTemplate` reactively. Is there a way to do this so it affects all routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be a function to be reactive:

```
layoutTemplate: function(){
   return Session.get('fullscreen') ? 'layoutFull' : 'layout'
}
```

Also, why two functions?
You need just one since this is the negation of clicked Session

Comment: It's bound to two different layouts – what else would you do? Thanks much more clear.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't notice those are two different layots, my bad, then those events are ok